# Python/WSGI: Determining HTTP request charset

Tags: python, http, encoding, wsgi

Is there any way to reliably determine in which character set browser sends data?
I'm jumping around Accept-Charset/Accept-Language headers in conjunction with server locale (as most web-sites are not *that* world-wide), but still, nothing comes to mind.

Specifically, MSIE sends data in locale's charset if the user types in address bar custom values (that's why I started to count in Accept-Language header).

The second question is, can I determine charset for both GET and POST or there is a chance that data would be in different encodings?

Comment: You can examine the HTTP header fields but usually, the web framework should do that for you and convert the string data to unicode. Maybe it would be better to explain what errors you get or what doesn't work.

Comment: The problem is I _am_ writing custom framework. So decoding incoming data is my responsibility

Comment: In the general case, no; there is no reliable way to determine the character set of untagged character data. If you know what to expect, you can apply some heuristics, but even then, that can be error-prone.